# Postgresql subquery in expression returns more than one row

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to map from a string value to a list of ids to use in an IN clause and haven't found a way to make it work yet.  Hopefully the query I've tried so far will make this clear:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM events
WHERE level_id IN (
  SELECT
  CASE
      WHEN skill_level='Beginner' THEN (SELECT id from levels WHERE code IN ('L1', 'L2'))
      WHEN skill_level='Intermediate' THEN (SELECT id from levels WHERE code IN ('L3', 'L4'))
      WHEN skill_level='Advanced' THEN (SELECT id from levels WHERE code IN ('L5', 'L6'))
  END ids
  FROM users WHERE id=2
)
```

Which could simplify for a 'Beginner' skill level user to this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM events WHERE level_id IN (1, 2)
```

I created a [fiddle to test this here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tP8MPuy2ks3Zfuo9jSAmJA/0).

I get the error "more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression" when I try this.  I've tried a number of permutations including the array() operator but I always get one error or another.

Maybe I'm fundamentally going about this the wrong way.  If anyone can suggest a fix for my query, or another way to accomplish the same thing it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sample data would really help your question here.

Comment: There is sample data in the linked fiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error "more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression" arises because of:

```sql
    WHEN skill_level=... THEN (SELECT id from levels WHERE code IN (...))
```

inside `CASE` statement.

**UPDATE**

Maybe the best would be to use suggestion of @gordon-linoff

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM 
    events E
    JOIN levels L ON E.level_id = L.id
    JOIN users U ON 
        ( U.skill_level='Beginner' AND  L.code IN ('L1', 'L2'))
        OR  (U.skill_level='Intermediate' AND L.code IN ('L3', 'L4'))
        OR  (U.skill_level='Advanced' AND L.code IN ('L5', 'L6'))
   WHERE
       U.id = 2
```

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tP8MPuy2ks3Zfuo9jSAmJA/4

**Previous answer**

Fix would be to use `CASE`-statement as predicate for `JOIN`:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM events 
WHERE
    level_id IN (
      SELECT 
              L.id
          FROM 
              users U
              JOIN levels L ON
                CASE
                    WHEN skill_level='Beginner' THEN  code IN ('L1', 'L2')
                    WHEN skill_level='Intermediate' THEN  code IN ('L3', 'L4')
                    WHEN skill_level='Advanced' THEN code IN ('L5', 'L6')
                END 
          WHERE
              U.id = 2
    )
```

Look on: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tP8MPuy2ks3Zfuo9jSAmJA/1

Answer (score 2):

Don't use a `case` like that.  Use simpler boolean logic:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM events
WHERE (skill_level = 'Beginner' AND level_id IN ('L1', 'L2')) OR
      (skill_level = 'Intermediate' AND level_id IN ('L3', 'L4')) OR
      (skill_level = 'Advanced' AND level_id IN ('L5', 'L6'));
```

I'm not sure what this logic is for:

```
FROM users WHERE id = 2
```

Your question does not explain that.

Comment: "skill_level" is in the users table, while "code" is in the levels table.  Please see the fiddle for clarification.

Comment: @GregButler . . . You have already been asked for sample data.  The question should clarify such things.

Answer (score 1):

I found a way that works in Postgresql 11.  Didn't work in 9.4, but as I am working in 11, that's fine.  I don't know if it's a good way, but it does work.  Alex Yu's answer might be better but I haven't done any performance testing.  Here it is for what it's worth:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM events
WHERE level_id = ANY(ARRAY(
SELECT
CASE
    WHEN skill_level='Beginner' THEN ARRAY(SELECT id from levels WHERE code IN ('L1', 'L2'))
    WHEN skill_level='Intermediate' THEN ARRAY(SELECT id from levels WHERE code IN ('L3', 'L4'))
    WHEN skill_level='Advanced' THEN ARRAY(SELECT id from levels WHERE code IN ('L5', 'L6'))
END ids
FROM users WHERE id=2
));
```

| count |
| --- |
| 3 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tP8MPuy2ks3Zfuo9jSAmJA/3)

Comment: You found a good answer. Essentially it's the same as mine but has less letters. Actually @GordonLinoff maybe gave the best answer

Comment: But maybe the best answer would be: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tP8MPuy2ks3Zfuo9jSAmJA/4

Answer (score 0):

It misses a key in `levels` table. You should add a skill_level column to link skill_level users. Then it becomes easier to make your query.

See the [example here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fpjL41h1GimERxWJBcDG7W/0)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I have to work with the tables as they are currently structured.  This is a simplified example that demonstrates my problem, not my actual real-world tables.